# Trying to select column BY in query, however query doesn't read it as a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

It seems Google Sheets has issues reading column BY. BX and BZ work. BY has the same type of information.

My theory is that `"SELECT BY"` is some sort of query argument.

```
=QUERY(VBOM!R5:GJ2811,"SELECT BY",1)
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## use `` ` `` like:

```
=QUERY(VBOM!R5:GJ2811, "select `BY`", 1)
```

---

```
=QUERY(data!B2:CL, "select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, `BY`, BZ, CA, BA 
                    where J = 'Industry Certification'", 0)
```

[image: 3]